# nodejs i18next is not translating string

Tags: node.js, i18next

I have this `err:authentication:invalid_token` in json file. folder is setup as `locales/vi_VN/mynamespace-vi_VN.json`. However, it's not translating in the `console.log` below.

Any idea why?

```
i18n.init({
    debug: true,
    preload: ['vi_VN'],
    resGetPath: 'locales/__lng__/__ns__-__lng__.json',
    lng: 'en_GB',
    ns: 'mynamespace',
    sendMissingTo: 'fallback',
    fallbackLng: 'en_GB'
}, function(err, t) {
    console.log('i18n is initialized.')
    console.log('Translation on:', t('err:authentication:invalid_token', {
        lng: 'vi_VN'
    }))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i was using colon `:` in identifier. I need to change it to something else or put it in appropriate namespace